# Parse data to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, list

I would like to pass WSE to a data frame k_out's column[wse], since I want to iterate k from 1 to 10; however, I stuck in parse data in the data frame, any comment is much appreciated. 
Here is my code:

```
num_list = None
k_out = pd.DataFrame(columns=['wse'], index=num_list)
for k in range(1, 11):

    clusters = KMeans.train(parsedData, k, maxIterations=10,
    initializationMode="random")
    WSE = parsedData.map(lambda point: error(point)).reduce(lambda x, y: x 
    + y)
    k_out = k_out.append(WSE)
```

Comment: Noticed that you are following the spark documentation of `Kmeans`. If this is right then `parsedData` is the dataframe contains the data to do the `Kmeans` clustering. In your case if your data is inside `k_out` then you need to replace the `parsedDate` with your data

Comment: I'm kind of stuck in passing a series of data to a data frame, I was thinking about to save WSE in a list and pass it back it to k_out, but it was not working. Any hints that I  can store WSE to dataframe k_out? Thank you!

Comment: You can change a `series` to `dataframe` by doing this `series.to_frame()`